I use scottplot and the line in the graph has high and low peaks and is not linear
I'm trying to draw a line using scottplot version 5 in WPF on .NET 8 using C#. I read on the site and searched on Google on how to make the line progressive without having the peaks as in the graph
I actually tried very little, because I couldn't find something that gave me the right approach to solving the problem.
I would like the line not to be displayed like in the following
image
I insert the function piece. In short the code takes data from a csv. The Date and Close field and apply them on the respective X and Y axis
private void Test()
{
    //Plot myPlot = new();
    var plt = WpfPlot1.Plot;

    var lines = File.ReadAllLines("./files/result.csv").Skip(1);
    var dates = lines.Select(line => DateTime.ParseExact(line.Split(';')[0], "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).ToArray();
    var closes = lines.Select(line => double.Parse(line.Split(';')[1])).ToArray();

    DateTime start = dates.First();

    var sig = plt.Add.Signal(closes);
    sig.Data.XOffset = start.ToOADate();
    sig.Data.Period = 1.0;

    plt.Axes.DateTimeTicksBottom();

    WpfPlot1.Refresh();
}

Date;Close
2019-01-02;1,10588
2019-01-03;1,10991
2019-01-04;1,13849
2019-01-05;1,13776
2019-01-06;1,13659
2019-01-07;1,15636
2019-01-08;1,15891
2019-01-09;1,11274
2019-01-10;1,11709
2019-01-11;1,14349
2019-01-12;1,14999
2019-01-13;1,1395
2019-01-14;1,15414
2019-01-15;1,15463
2019-01-16;1,11159
2019-01-17;1,11678
2019-01-18;1,13906
2019-01-19;1,14337
2019-01-20;1,13417
2019-01-21;1,14896
2019-01-22;1,15415
2019-01-23;1,1103
2019-01-24;1,11364
2019-01-25;1,14406
2019-01-26;1,14309
2019-01-27;1,12859
2019-01-28;1,14292
2019-01-29;1,15261
2019-01-30;1,11206

I forgot to add a dataset
I thank you for the time you dedicated to me

You seem to be asking about smoothing the curve. If ScottPlot does not provide anything suitable, you could use another library or implement it yourself.

The LineCharts (v2) library has a smoothing example. Maybe that works for you.
https://livecharts.dev/docs/wpf/2.0.0-rc2/gallery

I think you want to smooth your data, since it seems like that data shouldn't be a smooth line unless you actively smooth it.
ScottPlot has some support for smoothing on scatterplots (by setting scatter.Smooth = true), but for signal plots you should smooth it yourself. For scatter plots ScottPlot just spline-interpolates with Smooth = true set, which is probably not what you want. You probably want a 1-week moving average or something like that, and you should implement that yourself or use a stats library (MathNET.Numerics might be a good bet?).

Hi @Clemens I did something with smoothing and it should be what I was trying to do. However, I would like some advice, if I'm not asking too much, as soon as I post a comment with the updated code.

Hi @Jos A thousand thanks. I will keep this library in mind and try it as soon as possible

Hi @Ben Yes. it is a smoothing of the data without exaggerating. moving average no, not for the moment. it's more of a smoothing out to find a smooth direction without having spikes. Thank you so much for the library

Code image  I managed to create the sanding and I think it came out sufficiently. I have another problem, if I'm not asking too much, to solve. I would like to replace the numbers with the names of the month. I created some code and couldn't get it to work. the only times he gave values ​​without making mistakes, he gave values ​​like 40 thousand
